# fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, make, numpy

Can you please help with this?

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/tf-faster-rcnn/lib$ sudo pip2 install numpy
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading numpy-1.12.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.5MB 64kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.0
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/tf-faster-rcnn/lib$ make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'utils/bbox.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'utils.cython_bbox' extension
{'gcc': ['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function']}
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c utils/bbox.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/utils/bbox.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function
utils/bbox.c:346:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
 #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1

mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/tf-faster-rcnn/lib$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxine1-bin
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using the following command:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-I /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include $CFLAGS"
```

Comment: Why `dist-packages` and not `site-packages` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you may not have installed numpy correctly. Try uninstalling and then installing it again using:

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```